# Exception: org.exolab.castor.xml.ValidationException was not added to the list of sorted types

Tags: websphere, ear, castor

I am trying to deploy EAR file on Websphere Application Server but while deploying it's showing an error.

ERROR CODE:

```
SEVERER: Exception org.exolab.castor.xml.ValidationException was not added to the list of sorted types.

The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.exolab.castor.xml.ValidationException. Fix the build path then try building this project.
```

I am using Castor in my project but it's there in classpath which i am setting through Shellscript.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies need to be expressed to the application server runtime, not added to some shell variable or standalone java invocation. Either package them in your application or create an isolated shared library and associate it with your dependent application.